# Getting error Cannot extract package using Node-webkit

Tags: json, node.js, node-webkit

I am getting the following message when i am trying to to run one desktop application using Node-webkit.

```
Cannot extract package 

Failed to unzip the package file: C:\Documents
```

Actually i have downloaded the node-webkit and placed inside c drive(`i.e-C:\node-webkit-v0.11.5-win-ia32`) after unzip it.I created two file i.e-index.html and package.json in another location(`i.e-C:\Documents and Settings\Subhrajyoti\Desktop\htdocs\desktop1`).When i run command(`i.e.C:\node-webkit-v0.11.5-win-ia32\nw C:\Documents and Settings\Subhrajyoti\Desktop\htdocs\desktop1`) in cmd,it gave me the above message.I have the below file to run.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Node Webkit</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Node-webkit!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

> package.json:

```
{
  "name" : "nw-demo",
  "main" : "index.html",
  "window" : {
    "toolbar" : true
  }
}
```

Please help me to run this app successfully.

Comment: Try putting the argument in quotes... ie. `C:\node-webkit-v0.11.5-win-ia32\nw "C:\Documents and Settings\Subhrajyoti\Desktop\htdocs\desktop1"`.  It seems to be unhappy with the space in the path name.

Comment: @ Ben :Ok..can you say me ,I have one app made using html+js+css.I need to create its desktop app using node-webkit by using my own image.